# Mount folder automatically in home directory for every old&new user

Tags: ubuntu, mount, directory

I want to allow access to /var/www/dev/ to every user in my system (+50) via their home directory

For one particular user I can do:

> mkdir /home/user_name/www_dev mount --bind /var/www/dev/
>   /home/user_name/www_dev

And then make this configuration permanent by editing /etc/fstab:

> /var/www/dev  /home/user_name/www_dev    none    bind    0       0

My question is: the above is for 1 particular user, how can I make this work for every user in the system? and automatically when I create a new user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a symlink instead of mount.  You can accomplish this easily by creating a file in /etc/profile.d.  In the file add the command to create the symlink.  Since the scripts in /etc/profile.d run as the user, the command would be:

```
ln -fs /var/www/dev ~/www_dev
```

Using the system wide profile will ensure the symlink is created even if the user removes it.

This will only work if the user is using an interactive login shell, e.g. ssh or su.  See https://askubuntu.com/questions/438150/scripts-in-etc-profile-d-being-ignored for more information on types of login shells and startup scripts.

For more information on how /etc/profile.d works see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64258/what-do-the-scripts-in-etc-profile-d-do

Another way to do this is to use the useradd command and make use of /etc/skel. http://linux.die.net/man/8/useradd

When using useradd, anything in the /etc/skel directory gets copied to the new user's home directory.  You could place a symlink in /etc/skel using the source's absolute path and destination's relative path.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Some users are connecting via SFTP (Filezilla & WinSCP) and some via Webmin File Manager (Webmin) so it may not work at login time, is there anyway to create and make the symlink permanent when the user is created?

Answer (score 0):

I hope i understand the question:

I would use symlinks instead of bind mount.

For bind mount add it to .bashrc or distribution related file so it will be set every time user is logged on.

To do it for all users create a script reading /etc/passwd for users and do the command in a for statement.

To do it for new users edit the default .bashrc file or create a new one

---

Mike is a copycat... copied from me and added links ... dump